# How to make ComboBox boarder to be Fixed 3D

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I need to Make Combobox Boarder style to be Fixed3D , How I could do that?

Comment: Isn't that the default for a combobox?

Comment: No It shows as Flat

Comment: Hack solution, put a panel/bevel behind the combo slightly bigger than the control with the board style you want

Comment: @Hursey I tried to do that but the problem that ComboBox has boarder that I cannot remove (It shows as two rectangle one inside another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a custom control at Nuget "[Syncfusion ComboBoxAdv](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/comboboxadv/overview)" (It is a part of he Syncfusion Essential Tools for Windows Forms  [Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Tools.Windows/)) that allow me to change boarder type and many much other properties.

It have multiple type of **Boarder3DStyle** property:

- *RaisedOuter*
- *SunkenOuter*
- *RaisedInner*
- *Raised*
- *Etched*
- *SunkenInner*
- *Bump*
- *Sunken*
- *Adjust*
- *Flat*